# Is filterrific still being worked on?

Tags: filterrific

I'm trying to get a PR reviewed and it's going nowhere. I'm asking on SO to see if anybody here might know, is [Filterrific](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific/) still being worked on? There are a few PR's, lots of issues, and the author has yet to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `filterrific gem` myself. I have also experienced bad respond on issues & seems like the author is not so active himself.

Gem authors are also not obligated to give support but if they do its always a plus.

But to be fare author himself has used a lot of times to create good documents. At first when I was setting up the gem, I also had issue but if you read his documents carefully [(*read here*)](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/), you will understand the most.

I also recommend you to take a look at his demo app source code [(*found here*)](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific_demo)

By looking at the codes you will always set together stuff to create your own `scope`.

You can also follow all questions related to `filterrific gem` on SO [(*here*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filterrific)